# Quick relatively sharp upper bound for the largest singular value of $m \times n$ matrix $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there anything analogous to the [Gershgorin Circle Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) but for the singular values of an $m \times n$ matrix $X$? I'm interested in a relatively sharp upper bound for the largest singular value of such an $X$.

Answer (score 0):

For a matrix $A$ one has $|\lambda(A)| \le \parallel A^{k} \parallel^{\frac{1}{k}}$. Now $\sigma_i(X) = \sqrt{\lambda_i{(XX^{T})}}$. Take $A = XX^{T}$ and $\parallel (XX^{T})^{k} \parallel ^{\frac{1}{k}}$ will be a bound for $ \lambda(XX^{T})$ therefore for $ \sigma(X)^{2}$.